# Is it possible to get browser dev tools for a specific frame?

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, google-chrome

If I'm doing Facebook application development I often find myself wanting run JavaScript in the iframe where my page is embedded, which is fairly cumbersome. It would also be nice (though my main priority is just being to on the fly run some javascript) if there was a way to run something similar to the chrome dev tools or firebug specifically on that one frame.

Do I have any options for debugging in a single frame?

Comment: Maybe this could be useful: http://blog.chromium.org/2011/10/new-developer-tools-experimental-apis.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firebug it's possible by using the [cd()](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#cd.28window.29) function. E.g.: cd(window.parent.frames[1])

Answer (score 0):

I ended up embedding Firebug lite inside of the iframe for superusers, which I think I should be doing in the first place so our designer can get some feedback on the iPad and things.

I also noticed that there is a dropdown (or I guess drop-up in this case) menu in the chrome-dev channel for specifying which frame you are working in, similar to the `cd()` command styrr mentioned.